# Varnish Hangs Every 1-3 Days After Websocket Implementation

Tags: varnish, memory-usage

After implementing a varnish -> nginx -> nodejs websocket pipeline (previously we had been using iptables to port forward), we started experiencing a freeze in varnish every 1-3 days. Checking some of our logs, I can't find any errors, but I did notice that memory was getting very high. However, before the websocket configuration change, the memory was allowed to get much higher. At first, I thought that varnish was simply running out of available connections, so I increased the maximum number of threads to 5000.

The reason we had switched from iptables to this new pipeline was to enable URL routing at the HTTP level and client IP forwarding to our backend.

I've googled pretty hard, but all I can find are glowing articles about why varnish won't run out of memory rather than what to do when it does... can anyone help? For what it's worth, we have something like 80G of RAM so capacity isn't an issue.

Comment: We also noticed that since the Websocket introduction, there has been extreme volatility in the number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we had a Websocket that was not correctly closing on the client side after an authentication failure. It would retry every 10 seconds and this caused an amplification of the issue. Maybe Varnish was doing the right thing keeping the zombie connections alive assuming that closing the browser did in fact sever the connections.